# WebView not working again after close

Tags: java, webview, javafx

I am trying to instantiate many JFrames with WebView, it will work as long as after opening the first WebView, at least one WebView is still alive and the JFrame (along with everything else) arent disposed of.

After some checking, it seems that after closing the all WebView JFrame, the Platform.runLater() no longer runs on the next instantiation of the JFrame with the WebViewPanel.

The following is the simplified code:

```
public class WebViewPanel{
    private JFXPanel jfxPanel;
    private WebView view;
    private WebEngine webEngine;
    private JPanel panel;
    public WebViewPanel(JPanel panel){
        this.panel = panel;
        panel.setVisible(true);
        createScene();

    }
    private void createScene(){
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){ //Runnable no longer runs after all JFrames with WebViewPanels are closed
                jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
                view = new WebView();
                webEngine = view.getEngine();
                jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
                panel.add(jfxPanel);
                jfxPanel.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So, what must I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: I think you should be using a [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html).  Maybe it is there and you have just oversimplified your code example.  An [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might help.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Platform exits itself if not explicitly set.

Here's what you need to do just after

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){ // ..code
```

add `Platform.setImplicitExit(false);` at the first row

so your new code will be -

```
private void createScene(){

    Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        @Override
        public void run(){
            jfxPanel = new JFXPanel();
            view = new WebView();
            webEngine = view.getEngine();
            jfxPanel.setScene(new Scene(view));
            panel.add(jfxPanel);
            jfxPanel.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Just FYI if you are trying to display the panel more than once there is no need to call createScene() add the JFXPanel to a JFrame(preferable panel works fine too) with a static reference. dispose the frame to close it and when again you need to show this simply set the same frame setVisibale(true);. everytime calling this frame you can also check if the static reference of this frame points to null(representing first call) then call createscene() else just set the static reference to visible.